# Google sheets, OR logic function

Tags: google-sheets, logic

I have searched, but do not get what I am doing wrong?

How do you use the OR logic function? I have double checked and seem to be doing every thing right.

**Formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(OR(FIND("Wisconsin", A2, 1), FIND("All", A2, 1)), "Out of State"), ""))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would use regexextract and use the pipe "|" which is the or operator:

```
=arrayformula(if(istext(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"Wisconsin|All")),"Out of State",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with OR, it is with FIND. You could use Lookup:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(lookup("Wisconsin", $A2, 1), LOOKUP("All", $A2, 1)),"Out of State", ""), "")
```

But I would suggest nested ifs like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(($A2:$A)="Wisconsin","",(IF(($A2:$A)="All","",(if(($A2:A)="","","Out of State"))))))
```